# why is this query invalid?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Why is this query invalid? When I write 
just SRV_ID instead of  vt_exam_details.SRV_ID everything works just fine

```
 cl_id
, cl_name_last as CUSTOMER
, vt_animals.an_type
, vt_exam_details.SRV_ID
, vt_services.srv_desc
, vt_exam_details.ex_fee
from vt_clients
join vt_animals using (cl_id)
join vt_exam_headers using (an_id)
join vt_exam_details using (ex_id)
join vt_services using (srv_id)
```

Error:

```
Error at Command Line:5 Column:3
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "VT_EXAM_DETAILS"."SRV_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thanks.

Comment: is vt_exam_details the right table for SRV_ID?

Comment: well.your error says that..the table vt_exam_details doesn't have any column named "SRV_ID".

Comment: SQL> describe vt_exam_details    
 EX_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 LINE_ITEM       NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 SRV_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 EX_FEE        NOT NULL NUMBER(6,2)
 EX_DESC         VARCHAR2(50)
}

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here, so writing a little messy. as you can see I have that srv_id

Answer (score 1):

Because the table `vt_exam_details` is not in the FROM clause?

Comment: but my other tables are not in the FROM clause either

Comment: Could you post the columns in the table? easier to help that way. Also, could the case be different for the column names?

Comment: SQL> describe vt_exam_details EX_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(6) LINE_ITEM  NOT NULL NUMBER(6) SRV_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(6) EX_FEE NOT NULL NUMBER(6,2) EX_DESC  VARCHAR2(50) } –

Comment: I think the answer is that, since I have join vt_services using (srv_id) I don't have to specify the table name for attribute srv_id

Comment: Exactly! otherwise you would get error for `vt_exam_details.ex_fee` too.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a SRV_ID in table VT_EXAM_DETAILS?

Comment: SQL> describe vt_exam_details EX_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(6) LINE_ITEM  NOT NULL NUMBER(6) SRV_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(6) EX_FEE NOT NULL NUMBER(6,2) EX_DESC  VARCHAR2(50) } –

Comment: I think the answer is that, since I have join vt_services using (srv_id) I don't have to specify the table name for attribute srv_id